# extract specific lines based on another file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a folder containing text files. I need to extract specific lines from the files of this folder based on another file input.txt. I tried the following code . But it doesn't work.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    if(NF>1)f=$3
    else A[f,$1]
    next
  }
  (FILENAME,$3) in A {
    print > ( todir "/" FILENAME )
  }
' todir=/home/alan/Desktop/output  FS=\* /home/alan/Desktop/input.txt FS=" " *



file1    
PHE .0      10  .0      0
ASP 59.8    11  59.8    0    
LEU 66.8    15  66.8    0
ARG 21.0    16  21.0    0

file2
SER 57.9    43  57.9    0
PHE 2.4     44  2.4     0   
GLN 86.1    49  83.2    2.9
THR 33.2    50  33.2    0
SER 10.2    51  .9      9.3

input.txt

*file1
10
16
*file2
43
44
49

Desired output

file1
PHE 0       10    0     0
ARG 21.0    16  21.0    0

file2
SER 57.9    43  57.9    0
PHE 2.4     44  2.4     0
GLN 86.1    49  83.2    2.9
```

Comment: Setting FS twice on the command line is dubious.  It might work with GNU `awk`, though I'm not convinced; it won't with most other variants.

Comment: It will work with all awks. Setting FS to different values between files is one of the very few valid reasons to set a variable in the arg list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 3,
`$3` needs to be changed to `$2`.

Since *asterisk* is the field separator in `input.txt`, the (empty, non-existent) string before it is counted as $1 and the file name that comes after it as $2.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    if(NF>1)f=$2
    else A[f,$1]
    next
  }
```